# Organizing methods of one class into packages

Tags: java, methods, code-organization

I' d like to know if there is a way of putting some NOT STATIC methods into separate packages without passing variables? I mean if for example my method is using 7 class variables - if there is a way of putting the method separately from the class? My problem is only organization of the methods within the class code and not the functionality.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want?

Comment: I mean if a have static methods - I put them in different package without problems. But I want to put non static methods separately from the class... So as I see from Mark's answer it is impossible...

Comment: I mean [edit] your question to show how you would use the code if it was possible. What you are asking seems to be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I don't really get your question, So you want non-static methods in separate packages? What's the without passing variables part?

Comment: I agree it s little bit "XY problem" style - but my question is like "if Y is possible"? I was looking for  something like 
 int a = packagename.non_static_method_that_uses_class_variables();

Comment: Sooo you want a non-static method that can use another class's variable?

Comment: Mine Rockers, 
My "X- problem" is organizational. I have a Class with 30 non static methods & 20 class level variables so I just wanted to organize my methods without actually touching the code. So all static methods I ve just put into separate package(s). Now I was wonder if there is a way to do something with non static methods... As I understand it s impossible...

Answer (score 0):

No. In java, all methods have to be inside classes. You can split a class into multiple classes, but then of course the methods can only use the class variables of their class.

Also, while classes can be in different packages, methods of one class cannot. They can't even be in different files.

Answer (score 0):

**Variables** and **Methods** are member of a **class**. It is not possible that a method can stand alone on its own without a **class** on it. You can manage your desired methods in different classes but you can't split the class and method.